# simple question about jquery selector

Tags: jquery, selector

for example, if I have:

```
var $target = $("div#target");
```

and then, I would like to pass this jquery object $target to another javascript function I defined myself, like:

```
 function f(xml, $div_t)
  {

  }
```

inside the function f, is there someway I can retrieve the original div's ID from the object $div_t?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$div_t.attr("id")
```